# What is missing?

Tags: drivers, printing

Trying to install a printer driver for Canon MB2320.  Have downloaded the driver and am executing the following command and receiving the response shown below:

```
kevin@WildBlueCoyote:~/Downloads/cnijfilter2-5.00-1-rpm$ sudo bash install.sh
[sudo] password for kevin:
```

==================================================

> Canon Inkjet Printer Driver
>   Version 5.00
>   Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2014

==================================================

```
An error occurred. A necessary package could not be found in the proper location.
```

What is missing, or am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 3):

You downloaded the wrong file. You downloaded a `rpm package archive`, but you have to download a `debian package archive` Ubuntu uses `.deb` files to install packages, not `.rpm`.

Download `cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz` with this command.

```
wget http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0100006265/01/cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz
```

Extract the content with this command :

```
tar xvzf cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz
```

Install the driver with this command :

```
cd cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb
./install.sh
```